# Java - Applet doesn't display anything?

Tags: java, swing, applet

I'm new to creating an applet, and I started to create one. However, when I did so, I get nothing displayed in my applet. (i.e just an empty applet). Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

```
    package Dictionary;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

import BankAccount.BankGUI;

public class DictGUIDriver extends JApplet {

private static final int APPLET_WIDTH = 650; 
private static final int APPLET_HEIGHT = 400; 

private DictGUIMain dictGUI; 

public void init()
{
    dictGUI = new DictGUIMain(); 
    getContentPane().add(dictGUI);
    setSize(APPLET_WIDTH,APPLET_HEIGHT); 
}
}
```

and

```
package Dictionary;

 import javax.swing.*; 

public class DictGUIMain extends JPanel 
{ 
private JTextField fileTextField; 
private JLabel fileLabel;
private JPanel panel; 
//have a constructor for the frame 

public DictGUIMain()
{
    //create the dictionary object here Dictionary dict = new Dictionary(); 
    panel = new JPanel(); 
    fileLabel = new JLabel("Choose File: ");
    final int FIELD_WIDTH = 20; 
    fileTextField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);

    panel.add(fileLabel);
    panel.add(fileTextField);

    //create the button stuff here 

}
```

}

Comment: You never call `add(Component)` in the `DictGUIMain` constructor. You have to add components to the panel in order to get the program to display them.

Comment: @LuxxMiner Thanks for the help! I'm a bit confused though, would I just create a panel in `DictGUIMain` and add the other things to the panel? I changed the code above, and I still get nothing showing up in the JApplet

Comment: You extend `JPanel` in the `DictGUIMain` class, that means that an instance of this class is a `JPanel`. Your `private JPanel panel;` is a seperate `JPanel`, but that doesn't change the fact that you didn't add anything to the `DictGUIMain` panel. Call `this.add(panel);` or `add(panel);` at the end of the constructor and it will likely work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I understand my mistakes now and it worked :)